# Why regex_search does not require namespace

Tags: c++, std

I'm trying to understand why the code below compiles without problems in VS2012 and GCC 4.8.3:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::wregex brackets_regex(L"");
    std::wcmatch bracket_match;

    wchar_t expr[80] = L"";

    regex_search(expr, bracket_match, brackets_regex);
}
```

As far as I could find, regex_search is part of namespace std, but neither of the compilers require std::. Why is that allowed?

Comment: do you have `using std;` anywhere or implicitly included?

Comment: Nope, if you try that exact code, it will compile.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl

Comment: @EricFinn, could that cause problems between boost and std namespaces? Also, would you care to elaborate it as an answer?

Comment: N.B. the code is valid (due to ADL) and does compile with GCC 4.8 but the `<regex>` implementation is incomplete and doesn't work. It's finished in GCC 4.9

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That code compiles because of [Argument Dependent Lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup). Since the arguments are of types from the `std` namespace, that namespace is tagged as an 'associated namespace' and name resolution considers candidates from that namespace.

> could that cause problems between boost and std namespaces?

It's possible it can create ambiguity, resulting in errors.

```
namespace A {
    struct AA {};
}

namespace B {
    struct BB {};
    void foo(A::AA, BB) {}
}

namespace A {
    void foo(AA, B::BB) {}
}

int main()
{
    A::AA a;
    B::BB b;
    foo(a, b);
}
```

Also I think some compilers might implement it incorrectly, especially in conjunction with two-phase lookup, resulting in either compiling ill-formed code or failing to compile correct code, or even resolving a name to the wrong entity.

If you're encountering a problem you think might be related to ADL you'll have to provide details to get a more specific answer.

Comment: Could that cause problems between boost and std namespaces?